# Navigation Item's click or touch event sometimes does not being fired

Tags: ios, events, uinavigationitem

Most of the time navigation item in navigation bar works fine.
Navigation bar is hidden before user taps screen.
Navigation bar moves using `[[self navigationContoller] setNavigationBarHidden:YES/NO animated:YES]`
However, sometimes navigation item does not fire touch up inside event.
This is snippet of one of them.
`[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(someFunc) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`
Button animates fade out and in just like being touched fine, but event does not being fired.
But when I make navigation bar to hide and emerge again by tapping screen, navigation items works fine again.
What's the problem? I have totally no idea.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UIImageView`.
I added both default `UIBarButtonItem` and customized `UIBarButtonItem` using `UIImageView` and `UITapGestureRecognizer` to navigationBar for test. Then when I faced the problem again, the default `UIBarButtonItem` did not respond but customized `UIBarButtonItem` worked fine.

This is my sample code.

```
UIImage buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage" inBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
UIImageView buttonImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:buttonImage];
UITapGestureRecognizer buttonTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(targetFunction)];
[buttonImageView addGestureRecognizer:buttonTapGesture];
UIBarButtonItem *bbiButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonImageView];
```